# How to let div align left?

Tags: css

I want my div from this

```
-------------------------------
|div A                        |
-------------------------------
|div B                        |
-------------------------------
|div C                        |
-------------------------------
```

https://jsfiddle.net/apss/tqap7oc3/

to this one

```
-------------------------------
|div A         |div B         |
-------------------------------
|div C                        |
-------------------------------
```

I knew this may be a very simple question. Pardon me! Because it works fine neither `float:left` or `display:inline`. Help me.

Comment: Float? Display: inline-block?

Comment: It will miss some borders. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/apss/tqap7oc3/3/

Comment: @apss1943 that's because in `subColumn` you have `border-top:none;`

Comment: It's better to redefine your mark-up and classes in order to achieve this rightly base on the fiddle link you provided. `subColumn` class seemed to me as misleading because div A and div B is more suitable for this class name in definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.firstColumn, .subColumn{
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #18786C;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
.firstColumn {
width: 50%;
}
.subColumn:nth-child(2){
width: 50%;
}
.subColumn:nth-child(3){
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
 <div>
  <div class = "firstColumn" >
  aaa
  </div>
  <div class = "subColumn" >
  bbb
  </div>
  <div class = "subColumn" >
  ccc
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This my solution. If possible i prefer inline-block instead of float.

```css
.topColumn {
    width: 46%;
    display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #18786C;
  padding: 5px;
}

.subColumn {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #18786C;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
 <div>
        <div class="firstRow">
   <div class = "topColumn" >
   aaa
   </div>
   <div class = "topColumn" >
   bbb
   </div>
        </div>
   <div class = "subColumn" >
   ccc
   </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eyfksp46/3/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how to do it, for example with float.

```
.firstColumn, .subColumn {width: 200px; float: left;}
.subColumn + .subColumn {clear: left; width: 414px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqap7oc3/4/

Widths are in pixels, you can use what you need, eg. percents, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a new class called "half" and added to the "firstColumn" and second "subColumn".

```
.half{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    border-top: 2px solid #18786C;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tqap7oc3/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
//add to css class
.firstColumn {
    float:left;
}

.subColumn {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div>
    <div class = "firstColumn" >
    aaa
    </div>
    <div class = "subColumn" >
    bbb
    </div>
    <div class = "subColumn" >
    ccc
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.firstColumn, .subColumn{
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #18786C;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}
.firstColumn {
    width: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.subColumn:nth-child(2){
    width: 50%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-left: none;
}
.subColumn:nth-child(3){
  border-top: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/apss/tqap7oc3/3/